# How to ensure that inheriting classes are implementing a friend function (ostream)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, std

I'd rather implement a non-friend function and directly mark the function as virtual.

But I'm in a situation where I'd like to ensure that a specific set of classes implement an overloading of

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, MyClass& myClass);
```

and I found no other way to link it directly to my class. (Other possibility of implementation of operator is moving it outside my class, without friend)

Syntax lords, do I have any way of properly implementing this rule ? (having children overriding << ostream operator)

Edit - Related subjects on following threads:

[Overloaded stream insertion operator (<<) in the sub-class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29885672/179910)

[virtual insertion operator overloading for base and derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50979946/179910).

Comment: Make that friend to call pure virtual method of your base class.

Comment: All good, thanks. Didn't thinked of it.

Comment: You not only can, but need to use the "dispatch through a virtual member function" method, otherwise you will lose polymorphism.

Comment: By the way, this at least nearly duplicates some older questions, such as: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29885672/179910, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/50979946/179910.

Comment: Trying to force implementors of derived classes to do something you think they ought to do rarely succeeds. Document what your base class requires; trust implementors to know their requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a pure virtual method - that will require inherited classes to overload it, then make friend output operator to call it. For example:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    virtual ~MyClass();
    virtual void output( std::ostream &os ) const = 0;

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MyClass& myClass)
    {
        myClass.output( os );
        return os;
    }
};
```